# android bluetooth low energy status = 59

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

my android application runs as central is connected to a peripheral, enables notifications and the peripheral starts sending.

my problem is that the connection is terminated after about 13 seconds.

below i have the logcat information.

What is status 59 of Bluetooth LE in Android?

```
BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91, auto: false
BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=3a9c080d-ae20-47ea-b34c-7ea7798204cc
BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91
BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91
BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91 Status=0
BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00001625-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123 enable: true
BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91
BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=59 clientIf=5 device=C5:7F:B0:8E:AA:91
BluetoothGatt: close()
BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=5
```

Comment: Does your android application run on Android 6.0 or higher?

Comment: yes it is running on a nexus 9 with android 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same issue. After some digging i found in our case statuscode 59 (or 0x3B hex) pointed to `HCI_ERR_UNACCEPT_CONN_INTERVAL`.

By examining the Bluetooth HCI snoop logs from my phone i discovered that the ble device is negotiating with the phone about connection parameters. The device requested a connection interval of 7.5ms and the phone rejected this. After three times (15ms) the device disconnected and resetted.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617061/android-6-0-marsmallow-ble-connection-parameters) saying the minimum connection interval in Android 6.0 has changed to 12.5ms. So if you adjust the connection interval that the device requests, you'll probably keep the connection.

Comment: ok. thats the problem i had a minimum connection interval of 7.5 ms. thanks.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was my problem too. Except in my case I had the device's MIN_CONN_INTERVAL set to 20ms, so it kept trying to renegotiate when I set high priority in Android.

Comment: @schoensn what does the status 15 mean ? Where can we get the list of statuses and its meaning returned by gatt ?

Comment: google helped me to find this list: http://allmydroids.blogspot.co.at/2015/06/android-ble-error-status-codes-explained.html