# Programmatically detecting changes to BLE connection parameters

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-7.0-nougat

I want some way to read the connection parameters programatically in Android BLE.

Android's `BluetoothGatt` class, as of API 21, provides these three modes to set up connection parameters.

> CONNECTION_PRIORITY_BALANCED
>   Connection paramter update - Use the connection paramters recommended by the Bluetooth SIG.
>
> CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH
>   Connection paramter update - Request a high priority, low latency connection.
>
> CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
>   Connection paramter update - Request low power, reduced data rate connection parameters.

These have been discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617061/android-6-0-marsmallow-ble-connection-parameters), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398766/android-ble-connection-time-interval).

Since none of these give me the connection interval that I want, so tried performing a connection update from the side of my peripheral. Luckily, that seems to work. After I send the connection update I can see in Logcat:

```
D/BluetoothGattServer: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX interval=1596 latency=0 timeout=512 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX interval=1596 latency=0 timeout=512 status=0
```

I don't care what interval the Android devices chooses, so long as it is between 1000ms and 2000ms. While it is easy to see this change occurring in the logs, I have yet to find a way to read the interval value programatically. I would like to make sure this update occurred so that I am not wasting battery life on my peripheral.

Answer (score 1):

No. But if you can detect the update from the peripheral side then you can send a notification to the central with the new parameters.