# Handling Notifications on Android with Multiple BLE Peripheral Connections

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

So, I am new to Android development and I am trying to connect my device to multiple BLE devices ([T-Wristband](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Wristband)) to receive frequent notifications (IMU sensor data less than 20 bytes at *50Hz*).

When connecting to multiple devices, I **miss data from one or more devices**. I suspect the reason is that my `BluetoothGattCallback` method, `onCharacteristicChanged`, is working on the same thread for all devices (**Note:** I have checked that by logging `Thread.currentThread.getName()`).

What I have tried:

**1. [Android 4.3: How to connect to multiple Bluetooth Low Energy devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237093/android-4-3-how-to-connect-to-multiple-bluetooth-low-energy-devices)**

> I suspect everyone adding delays is just allowing the BLE system to complete the action you have asked before you submit another one.

**Problem:** I cannot add delays when receiving notifications since it would interfere with my sampling rate, and I am not sure when I might receive new notifications from another device, or even the same device.

**2. [Android BLE multiple connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404018/android-ble-multiple-connections)**

> To achieve multiple BLE connections you have to store multiple `BluetoothGatt` objects and use those objects for a different `device`.

**In this regard:** I have tried writing a custom class for my device, `TTGODevice`, which saves an instance of the corresponding `BluetoothGatt` upon connection:

```java
public class TTGODevice {
  /* Bunch of psf constants */
  private BluetoothDevice device;
  private Context context;
  private Accelerometer acc;
  private BluetoothGatt server;
  private int deviceStatus;

  private final BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() { ...
  };

  public TTGODevice(Context context, BluetoothDevice device) {
    this.device = device;
    this.context = context;
    this.acc = new Accelerometer(); // My custom class for accelerometer on the T-Wristband device(s)
  }

  public void connect(boolean autoConnect) {
    server = device.connectGatt(context, false, bluetoothGattCallback);
  }

  /*Getters for device, server, and deviceStatus*/
}
```

In the `BluetoothGattCallback`, I override my `onCharacteristicChanged` as below:

```java
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

  byte[] bytes = characteristic.getValue();

  // updating the Accelerometer
  acc.update(bytes);
  Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

I have also tried using the exact instance of my `server` in the callback above, but I am out of luck.

```java
byte[] bytes = server.getService(SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID).getValue();
```

Long story short, I have been unsuccessful. I would appreciate any other relevant threads.

[**Note:** I have been suggested to use `Fragments` and/or `ViewModels`. I am not sure how they are relevant.]

Comment: Receiving a notification every 20ms from multiple devices might simply be too fast for BLE

Comment: Nothing is really wrong with your Java code. I guess it's the air traffic that is limited. Please use a short connection interval when you deal with much data from multiple connections. The default at ~50 ms will not be good enough for your case.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I'm afraid there are examples of such situations. [MBIENTLAB's MetaMotionR](https://mbientlab.com/metamotionr/), for instance, makes use of Bluetooth 4.0 BLE for such purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Emil. I think I will have to negotiate this **interval** on the slave/server-side, meaning my T-Wristband, as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617061/android-6-0-marshmallow-ble-connection-parameters). I am not sure what my current configs are, but I will try that.

Comment: You can also use the requestConnectionPriority to set this.

Comment: @EhsanPartovi, is it working now? I am also stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that BLE on Android cannot handle sampling rates at *50Hz* and higher. I am not sure if this is a BLE-related problem or if it has something to do with the `onCharacteristicCHanged` method being called too frequently. I solved this by sending larger packets of data every *50ms*, contrary to my original case at every *20ms*. Larger BLE data packets are possible starting from **Bluetooth 4.2**, which is controlled using the **MTU**, *Maximum Throughput Unit*. [This blog](https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-part-2-use-larger-att-mtu-2/)  helped me a lot in understanding the underlying mechanism.

When receiving large packets of data over BLE at high sampling rates, it is best to use `gatt.requestMtu(MY_DESIRED_MTU)` with `MY_DESIRED_MTU > 20Bytes` inside the corresponding `BluetoothGattCallback` on Android. It should be noted that larger MTU means it takes longer for the data to be written on the BLE characteristic for the server device.

In short, I am using larger data packets and a larger delay to make up for the limitations in the sampling rate. For a sampling rate of *100Hz* on the IMU in the T-Wristband, I am using an MTU of *95 Bytes*, requested by the Android device, and a *50ms* delay on the timer on the T-Wristband. This allows me to receive five consecutive data samples every *50ms*.

Comment: The term "sampling rate" does not really make much sense here, since BLE is more like a stream of packets over an unreliable medium. Android accepts connection intervals down to 11.25 ms, which means ~88 packet exchanges/sec. If there is no interference and no overlaps of other radio activity, I don't see why you would not be able to send one packet per 11.25 ms. If you use long packets with the LE Coded PHY however, this might not be possible since those packets are longer than 11.25 ms. Android itself has no limitations. It all depends on the scheduler of the BLE controller in the phone.